# R mutate to create row to use sum() for same value in a different row

Tags: r

I want to use the mutate() function to make a row that adds the `after.tax` value when `month` is same.

this is the .csv file

```
month, category, occurrence, total, before-tax, after-tax
4, .hagwon,3.33,169830,169830,164225.61
5, .hagwon,11.33,577830,577830,576096.51
6, .hagwon,10,510000,510000,508470
6, .co,5,300000,300000,299100
```

I did this because the month, category, and occurrence are the fixed variables

```
income.raw <- income %>%
  select(month, category, occurrence)
```

and this to calculate the income and `after.tax`

```
income.raw %>%
  mutate("total" = case_when (category == ".hagwon" ~ (occurrence * 17000 * 3)
                              ,category == ".co" ~ (occurrence * 30000 * 2))) %>%
  mutate("before.tax" = total, "after.tax" = total * 0.967)
```

now, I want to add a row where it sums the `after.tax` when the `month` is identical. this is my effort but I can't seem to do it.

```
mutate("monthly.total" = case_when (
                                      for (i in length(income.raw$month)) {
                                        if(identical(income.raw$month[i],1)) {
                                          
                                        }
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop, just use `%>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(Total_after_tax = sum(after.tax, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: thank you! yes I should have used the group_by() function.